# Getting Location and getting GPS Settings in android

Tags: android, gps

i am developing one application in that i am successfully getting location but but before getting location i want to check my gps settings and if it is not enable ,display settings of gps from my app ,i wrote but its not working please tell me where i made mistake

myCode

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    progress = ProgressDialog.show(ContextAsync, "Loading data", "Please wait...");
  locationManagerAsync = (LocationManager) ContextAsync.getSystemService(ContextAsync.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (locationManagerAsync.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        providerAsync = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
    }else if (locationManagerAsync.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
        providerAsync = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;

    } else if (locationManagerAsync.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER)) {
        providerAsync = LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER;
        //Toast.makeText(ContextAsync, "Switch On Data Connection!!!!", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

 else 
 if(!locationManagerAsync.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)&&
  !locationManagerAsync.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {

        buildAlertMessageNoGps();
    }

}


@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    latlongDetails =new LatLongDetails();



    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(false);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
    providerAsync = locationManagerAsync.getBestProvider(criteria, false);


    location = locationManagerAsync.getLastKnownLocation(providerAsync);
    // Initialize the location fields
    if (location != null) {
        //  System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
        latAsync = location.getLatitude();
        lonAsync = location.getLongitude();



    } else {
        //Toast.makeText(ContextAsync, " Locationnot available",    
       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }



    List<Address> addresses = null;
    GeocoderAsync = new Geocoder(ContextAsync, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        addresses = GeocoderAsync.getFromLocation(latAsync, lonAsync, 1);

        String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
        String city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
        String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
        AddressAsync = Html.fromHtml(
                address + ", " + city + ",<br>" + country).toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        AddressAsync = "Refresh for the address";
    }



    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {  

    super.onPostExecute(result);
    progress.dismiss();
    onLocationChanged(location);
    Log.v("latAsync_lonAsync",latAsync+"_"+lonAsync);
    Intent intentAsync = new Intent(ContextAsync,Emerg.class);
    intentAsync.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);   
    intentAsync.putExtra("calculated_Lat", latAsync);
    intentAsync.putExtra("calculated_Lon", lonAsync);
    intentAsync.putExtra("calculated_address", AddressAsync);

    ContextAsync.startActivity(intentAsync);

}



@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    locationManagerAsync.requestLocationUpdates(providerAsync, 0, 0, this);
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
private void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ContextAsync);
    builder.setMessage("Your GPS seems to be disabled, do you want to enable it?")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 ContextAsync.startActivity(new    
   Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
            }
        });


    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
               }
           });
    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Comment: got any error? post it

Comment: no but it execute catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        AddressAsync = "Refresh for the address";
    }

Comment: I think it's context issue. try to create `locationManagerAsync` outside your `AsyncTask`

Comment: Show that stack trace from catch please

Answer (score 0):

In onPreExecute() try using:
...

else 
 if(!locationManagerAsync.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) **||**
  !locationManagerAsync.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {

```
    buildAlertMessageNoGps();
```

}
...

Comment: ya its work fine but if gps settings of go to settings and automatically it will go to activity without do any thing in gps settings

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing well, after viewing your code and problem, i got that you want only location from GPS.If that is enable then ok Otherwise show dialog for enable.

For achieve that you will remove two condition.

`else if (locationManagerAsync.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
        providerAsync = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
    }else if (locationManagerAsync.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER)) {
        providerAsync = LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER;
        //Toast.makeText(ContextAsync, "Switch On Data Connection!!!!", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }`

because of this you will not get gps enable popup dialog.

i think it will work.

Comment: ya its work fine but if gps settings of go to settings and automatically it will go to activity without do any thing in gps settings

Comment: @Durga you are directly going to `GPS_SETTING` that's fine. but when you navigate to setting and return back what happen? try

Comment: You can check your code flow and create logic for that. if you have any query then please ask me.